# How to link multiple children item to a single parent item?

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

I have a list of dates with properties and method I create with :

```
New CalendarDate('2018-XX-XX')
```

And for each date, I have a list of hours. I would like each of my hour to reference one single date.

At the moment, the solution I came from seems... inadequate, and I would like to understand the proper way to do it. So for each hour I create a new instance of Hour and pass the newly created date. I.E :

```
Class CalendarDate {
    dateString: string

    constructor(date: string) {
       this.dateString = date
    }

    getDate() {
       return this.dateString
    }
}

Class CalendarHour {
    date: CalendarDate

    constructor(date: CalendarDate) {
       this.date = date
    }
}

let date1 = new CalendarDate('2018-11-11')
let hour1 = new CalendarHour(date1)
let hour2 = new CalendarHour(date1)
```

I want to avoid creating a new CalendarDate for every CalendarHour, but I'd rather like each CalendarHour to refer to the same CalendarDate object. What would be a better approach than the one I came up with ?

Comment: That code looks perfectly fine to me. You only ever create a single `CalendarDate` and pass its reference around.

Comment: Ok thanks, it seemed a bit 'reversed' to me that the Hour would hold the Date